# Folding up URLs

Tags: hideshow

I am editing a document with lots of URLs in it, and I would like to automatically fold them down to just the last part of the URL so that they take up less room on the line, similar to the way `hideshow` folds up blocks of code. For example:

```
<http://www.foo.bar/baz.html>
```

To:

```
<baz.html>
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to do this, preferably in a way that is compatible with `goto-address`. I'm also wondering if it's possible to include a `+/-` symbol next to the URL like in `hideshowvis`.

Answer (score 6):

The URL parsing could probably be included, so take this just as an example, but the general idea is like this:

```lisp
(defun my/minify-urls (beg end)
  (interactive
   (if (region-active-p)
       (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (list (point-min) (point-max))))
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char beg)
    (while (re-search-forward "<\\w+:\\/\\/\\(:?[^>\\/]+\\/\\)*\\([^>\\/]+\\)>" end t)
      (message "matched")
      (let* ((all (match-string 0))
             (match (match-string 1))
             (ibeg (- (point) (length all) -1))
             (iend (- (point) (length match) -3)))
        (make-text-button iend (1- (point))
                          'len (- iend ibeg)
                          'state nil
                          'action (lambda (button)
                                    (let ((state (button-get button 'state))
                                          (len (button-get button 'len))
                                          (pos (button-start button)))
                                      (add-text-properties
                                       (- pos len) pos
                                       (if state '(invisible t) '(invisible nil)))
                                      (button-put button 'state (not state)))))
        (add-text-properties ibeg iend '(invisible t))))))
```

<kbd>RET</kbd> on the URLs to toggle expanded/minified state.

Comment: This looks to be a useful update to the built-in `goto-address-mode`. Please consider contributing.